# How to add class and id attributes to images added through django-cms?

Tags: django, plugins, image, django-cms

I'm using `cms.plugins.picture` plugin to add images to my website through django cms. I need to specify the class and id attributes of the images I'm adding in. How could I do that from cms or template system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's not possible. So, I used jQuery to add class and id in document ready handler.